# Have an error like SeleniumManagerException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I completed my web scraping project after 2 days opened jupyter notebook and ran the code getting these two errors. Can someone help in this

```
SeleniumManagerException: Message: Selenium manager failed for: C:\Users\dhara\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome.
ERROR   Wrong browser/driver version
```

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Python is not connecting to chrome webdriver.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.